# Changing a etoolbox toggle for the span of an environment

Tags: environments, etoolbox

I use the toggles of the [etoolbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package in my document. However, the document is long and gets modified a lot so sometimes the current state of the toggle is not clear when editing somewhere in the middle.

I thought it would be nice to define an environment that ensures:

1. the value of the toggle as I want it
2. reverts the value of the toggle at its end (so that the rest of the code is not effected by my edit)

I came up with this pseudocode/MWE that of course does not work but illustrates the idea:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\providetoggle{sometoggle}

\newenvironment{sometoggle}[1]
{%
    % oldtogglevalue = \gettoggle{sometoggle}
    \settoggle{sometoggle}{#1}
}{%
    % \settoggle{sometoggle}{oldtogglevalue}
    \ignorespacesafterend{} % ... this is a hidden second question as it does not work
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{sometoggle}{true}
        code that needs sometoggle to be true
        \begin{sometoggle}{false}
            code that need sometoggle to be false%
        \end{sometoggle}
    \end{sometoggle}

\end{document}
```

The arbitrary nesting of the new environment is especially difficult I feel.

Any ideas? Ty for reading,
Franz

Comment: You don't need to revert the toggle at the end of the environment since LaTeX will put the whole environment in a group. Unless you alter values globally the old value will be restored automatically. Don't use `{}` after `\ignorespacesafterend`. You're putting an extra space at the end of your environment. (`{}%` would help but you don't need that empty group to begin with.)

Comment: Ty ... about the `\ignorespaceafterend{}` does `{}` really add a space. I add the `{}` behind many command since my linter `chktex` complains otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\providetoggle{sometoggle}
\newenvironment{sometoggle}[1]
{%
    \settoggle{sometoggle}{#1}
}{}

\newcommand{\togglevalue}{``TOGGLE IS \iftoggle{sometoggle}{\textbf{TRUE}}{\textbf{FALSE}}''}

\begin{document}
    No env: \togglevalue
    
    \begin{sometoggle}{true}
        In env: \togglevalue
        
        \begin{sometoggle}{false}
            In second env: \togglevalue
        \end{sometoggle}
        
        In env: \togglevalue
    \end{sometoggle}
    
    No env: \togglevalue
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: .... stupid me. I did not even tried my code just assumed it would not work. Ty ..